# Imprimir otros valores en lugar de 1 o 0

Tags: c

Aquí está mostrando cuando es 0 False o True 1, pero nomás me arroja 1 o 0. ¿Cómo le puedo hacer para que me arroje "True" o "False" en vez de 1 o 0?

¿Y cómo le puedo hacer para cambiarlo a otra frase como correcto / incorrecto?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=18, b=19, c=20,formula;
    printf("Segundo trabajo de clases \n");
    formula= ( a!=b) && (b == b);
    printf("for (%d != %d) && (%d == %d), the output is : %d \n ", a ,b, b, b, formula );
    formula= ( a==b) && (c < b);
    printf("for (%d == %d) && (%d < %d), the output is : %d \n ", a ,b, c, b, formula );
    formula= ( a==b) || (c < b);
    printf("for (%d == %d) || (%d < %d), the output is : %d \n ", a ,b, c, b, formula );
    formula= ( a!=b) || (c <= b);
    printf("for (%d != %d) || (%d <= %d), the output is : %d \n ", a ,b, c, b, formula );
    formula= ( a!=b) || (c <= b);
    printf("for (%d != %d) || (%d <= %d), the output is : %d \n ", a ,b, c, b, formula );
    formula= !(a==b);
    printf("for (%d == %d), the output is : %d \n ", a ,b, formula );
     formula= !(a!=b);
    printf("for (%d != %d), the output is : %d \n ", a ,b, formula );
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No hay forma de imprimir directamente el resultado como un BOOL. Sin embargo podrías usar un ternario para imprimir un String.

```
printf("for (%d != %d) && (%d == %d), the output is : %s \n", a, b, b, b, formula ? "true" : "false");
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias ! esto era mas o menos lo que ocupaba! !